# Finding index of list item which is assembled by Fraction class

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the index of specifyed element in my list that looks like this for example 
Which is generated by xrange with Fractional.

```
>> print lst
[Fraction(1, 8), Fraction(1, 7), Fraction(1, 6), Fraction(1, 5), Fraction(1, 4),          Fraction(2, 7), Fraction(1, 3), Fraction(3, 8), Fraction(2, 5), Fraction(3, 7), Fraction(1,   2), Fraction(4, 7), Fraction(3, 5), Fraction(5, 8), Fraction(2, 3), Fraction(5, 7), Fraction(3, 4), Fraction(4, 5), Fraction(5, 6), Fraction(6, 7), Fraction(7, 8)]
```

I have been trying everything. 
Why doesn't this work.

```
lst.index(1,6)
```

or

```
lst.index( Fraction(1,6) )
```

and I have tried many more but I always get

```
print lst.index(Fraction(1,6))
ValueError: Fraction(1, 6) is not in list
```

Any advice ?

More on how I created the list :

```
for d in xrange(1,limit+1):
        for n in xrange(1,limit+1):
                x = Fraction(n,d)
                lst.append(x)
```

Comment: In case you want help - please update you question with errors you got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems fine to me...

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> d = [Fraction(1, 8), Fraction(1, 7), Fraction(1, 6), Fraction(1, 5), Fraction(1, 4),          Fraction(2, 7), Fraction(1, 3), Fraction(3, 8), Fraction(2, 5) , Fraction(3, 7), Fraction(1,   2), Fraction(4, 7), Fraction(3, 5), Fraction(5, 8), Fraction(2, 3), Fraction(5, 7), Fraction(3, 4), Fraction(4, 5), Fraction(5,6), Fraction(6, 7), Fraction(7, 8)]
>>> d.index(Fraction(1,6))
2
```

Comment: My trouble was that I was trying to index inside the range-loop.